# Does Parent-Child jobs concept exist in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.net scheduler for data migration from one database to another. I want to start a separate job for each database table data transfer. I have a parent job for data migration which triggers child jobs for each table. I want parent job to wait for all of its children jobs to finish but right now when I start parent job, it triggers all children jobs which keep on running but parent job gets completed as soon as it triggers all the job. 
thanks in advance..

Sample code is given below

```
 public class DataMigrationJob : IJob
   {
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        List<string> tableList  = somelist;
        foreach (var table in tableList)
        {
           JobDetailImpl job = new JobDetailImpl(jobKey, groupName, tableJobType,    true, true);
        if (!SchedulerProvider.Scheduler.CheckExists(job.Key))
        {
            context.Scheduler.AddJob(job, true, true);
        }
        context.Scheduler.TriggerJob(job.Key);
        }
    }             
}
```

Is there a proper way to keep parent job running until all children jobs are done?

I have an idea to make it work by using while loop which will call a function in condition and add wait, something like below

```
    public boolena AllChildrenJobCompleted(IJobExecutionContext context,             List<JobKey> jobKeys)        
    {
      runningJobsList = context.Scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
      //check if children jobs are part of this list
      //return false until list contains any of the child job
      //return true when list does not contain child jobs
    }
```

Later this function can be called inside execute function of parent job like this

```
      while(!AllChildrenJobCompleted(context,childJobs))
         {wait(1000);}
```

Not sure if it is the best pratice.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need child jobs at all? You can simply have one job, that creates a set of async [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx), runs them and waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

Accordingly to [quartz-documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-chain) there currently is no "direct" or "free" way to chain triggers with Quartz, but there are several ways you can accomplish it without much effort:

> - One way is to use a listener (i.e. a TriggerListener, JobListener or SchedulerListener) that can notice the completion of a job/trigger and then immediately schedule a new trigger to fire. This approach can get a bit involved, since you'll have to inform the listener which job follows which - and you may need to worry about persistence of this information. See the listener org.quartz.listeners.JobChainingJobListener which ships with Quartz - as it already has some of this functionality.
> - Another way is to build a Job that contains within its JobDataMap the name of the next job to fire, and as the job completes (the last step in its execute() method) have the job schedule the next job.

Comment: Thanks for your input, actually I want to display status of child jobs in quartz UI. In case one of the child  jobs is failed I should be able to re-trigger it from UI. Each child job is independent piece of work and the parent job is required because I need a single point where all child jobs can be triggered at once.